# Is there a way to determine the upstream web server with PHP?

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I'm developing a PHP web application that needs to send out a file in a server specific way, like so:

```
<?php
$server = get_upstream_web_server();

if ($server === 'nginx') {
  header('X-Accel-Redirect: smiley.png');
}
else if ($server === 'apache') {
  header('X-Sendfile: smiley.png');
}
else {
  echo file_get_contents('smiley.png');
}
```

Is there a way to get the name of the upstream server like the `get_upstream_web_server()` in the above example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).